# Should we have a "hagiology" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I learned a new word today: hagiology. It means:

> [hagiology](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hagiology)
> [hag-ee-ol-uh-jee, hey-jee-]
> noun
>
> 1. the branch of literature dealing with the lives and legends of the saints.
> 2. a biography or narrative of a saint or saints.
> 3. a collection of such biographies or narratives.

We have plenty of questions about saints and a good chunk of them are about the saints' lives or deaths.

I think these questions would benefit from an [hagiology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hagiology) tag. Would this be  a good idea?

Here's a few that could use it:

- [Is there a sense in which Stephen was the first Catholic saint?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27593/stephen-the-first-saint)
- [What exactly is the purpose of a Patron Saint?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/what-exactly-is-the-purpose-of-a-patron-saint)
- [Why does a beheaded saint have the halo above the stump?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18948/why-does-a-beheaded-saint-have-the-halo-above-the-stump)
- [Why is Mary Magdalene the patron saint of hairdressers?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33729/why-is-mary-magdalene-the-patron-saint-of-hairdressers)
- [What exactly is the purpose of a Patron Saint?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/what-exactly-is-the-purpose-of-a-patron-saint)

Comment: How would it be used differently from the [tag:saint] tag?

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm not sure at the moment. That's kind of why I asked the question.

Comment: Don't forget [Where are the tombs of Jesus' original 12 disciples?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/37233/9289)

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude That would be the perfect question to have the tag.